# I have a trouble with layout

Tags: css, layout

The link elements don't display correctly. I tried to set a line-height property for it, but it didn't work. Instead of this `<li>` elements got height property.

P.S Sorry for my english

```css
footer {
 width: 100%;
 background: #eee;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 text-align: center;
}

footer p {
 line-height: 40px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin:25px 20px 25px 0;
 padding: 0 25px;
 border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
}

footer ul {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 140px;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 25px 0;
 padding: 0;
 line-height: 40px;
}

footer li {
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 40px;
}

footer a {
 font-size: 25px;
 color: #aaa;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
 <p>Some text</p>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="fab fa-instagram"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="fab fa-telegram-plane"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class='fab fa-behance'></a></li>
 </ul>
</footer>
```

Comment: what are u trying to  do ! explain more!

Comment: in such cases i suggest use the flex in the style or the better way is to use the bootstrap it has good utilities for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
footer {
    width: 100%;
    background: #eee;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

footer p {
    line-height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:25px 20px 25px 0;
    padding: 0 25px;
    border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
}

footer ul {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 140px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 25px 0;
    padding: 0;
}

footer li {
    display: inline-block;
}

footer a {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #aaa;
    text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align:middle;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<footer>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="fab fa-instagram"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="fab fa-telegram-plane"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class='fab fa-behance'></a></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

this what u looking for?

Comment: And I believe `footer ul {display: inline;` will make it better.

Comment: Woah. I didn't know that vertical-align property applicable for something except table cells. Thanks a lot!